# Zend_Tool remove controller/action

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

I made a controller with Zend_Tool, but now I want to delete the controller. I know i can just delete the file, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with Zend_Tool, so i don't need to edit the .zfproject.xml myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to manually delete it.

> This functionality is slated for 1.10.
>   It was left out of the 1.8 and 
>   1.9 release for a couple of good reasons.  Since deleting is a pretty 
>   irreversible action, and sometimes is
>   also a recursive action- we wanted  to
>   ensure that the console/cli interface
>   at least had the capability to  ask
>   the user if deleting is OK, in other
>   words confirming the decision  to
>   delete something.  This way, people
>   will not accidentally delete  things
>   they will not be able to recover.
>
> -ralph

This is a post back in 1.10 but now it's in 1.11 and you still need to do it manually!

Comment: Yeah I saw that post aswell, but I was hoping that there would be a solution already :) Thanks anyways. I'm leaving it open for a bit longer, maybe someone else knows a solution.

Comment: @priktop You need to do that manually, by removing the action method in the controller and deleting the view script. You have also to edit the .zfproject.xml in the root of your project.

Comment: Let's keep this question in mind and add an update once Zend_Tool can manage deletions as well.

Comment: @markus i don't think it'll be anytime soon, but i too, am waiting for it ;X