# Removing or renaming actions

Tags: zend-framework

I am working on zend framework. I have mistakenly created some actions which are not useful for me now. So either I want to remove those actions or rename them. Is there any command by which I can do that. If no, how can I do it manually? Means which are the files I need to edit to remove or rename the action completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be enough to remove the `xxxxxAction()` methods from your controllers. This is how I've always done it. If you have view scripts associated to the action it's good to remove them too, for housekeeping purposes, although it's not strictly necessary. If you are using `Zend_Tool`, you'll also need to edit your `.zfproject.xml` file (it's used only by `Zend_Tool`).

Perhaps there is another way of doing it, using `Zend_Tool`, but I'm more used to work "the manual way".

**EDIT:**

Actually, there is a similar question already posted: [Zend_Tool remove controller/action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390058/zend-tool-remove-controller-action)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Well, I got answer from somewhere else. I think, It also needs to be removed from the .project.xml file other wise it will create problems while routing with indexController. In addition, view files should also be removed for memory management purpose.

Comment: @Sourabh: Yes, you are right. I overlooked the part about view files. I've just edited my answer to add the missing information.